# Nokia S40 Asha 2013: Options Command Removed in List Renderer

Tags: java-me, nokia-s40

Hi i'm developing Nokia S40 Series,
I used custom list renderer with Title, Subtitle, and thumb image.. In my form i have added options menu with addCommand() method.. Without obfuscate the options menu is visible, while I'm give obfuscate 10 while I'm click the list item the options menu going to hide...

In my list item action contains thread start... if i gave empty actions above cases works fine, but while give action for start thread the options menu going to hide, I unable find solution.

It works fine in Nokia305 Series and Nokia 200 Series But not in Nokia 501.